# Factor polynomial over $C, Q, R$, if one comlex root is given

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial is: $P(x)=x^6+x^4-x^3+x^2+1$. I need to factor it over $C, Q, R$ if one complex root is $\sqrt[3]{1}$. Also find all fields in which $P$ is reducible.

Now, I know how to find one factor of P using given complex root, and I end up with $(x^2+x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$, but how should I go about $(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$?

How can I find all fields in which $P$ is reducible?

Answer (score 1):

A start: To factor the quartic, it may be useful to find its roots.

Rewrite the quartic as $x^2(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+1)$.

Let $t=x+\frac{1}{x}$. Then to solve our quartic we first solve
$$t^2-2-t+1=0.$$

*Another way:* Our quartic is $\frac{x^5+1}{x+1}$. So its roots are certain $10$-th roots of unity.

Comment: thanks...what about second part, about finding all fields?

Comment: Technically it is reducible in all these fields, by the factorization you found. But maybe you mean expressible as a product of linear factors. Then we need a primitive tenth root of unity, and a primitive sixth root of unity (for the $x^2+x+1$ part). I don't know what all fields means. Any such field contains a primitive $30$-th root of unity, and any field that contains such a primitive $30$-th root will do the job.

Comment: it just says that: find all fields in which $P$ is raducible

Comment: It depends on the definition of reducible. If you [look here,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) you will be told that sometimes a polynomial which is not irreducible is called reducible. If we use that definition, then our polynomial is reducible over all fields. But they may mean **completely** reducible, that is, expressible as a product of linear factors. In the above comment, I described all subfields of the complex numbers over which our polynomial is completely reducible. To describe **all** fields, including the ones of non-zero characteristic, may be complicated.